# How can I take image size in kb, and Mb from the user to compress an image in android studio

Tags: java, android, image-compression, getimagesize

I want to get the image size in kb and MB from the user.
Like, I have one image, and the image size is 1Mb so I want to compress this image size according to the size given by the user.

I used this code :

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, imageQuality, stream);

    byte[] imageBytes = stream.toByteArray();
    return android.util.Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

But there is confusion about the image quality, It works well but here I can't measure how much quality it reduces because here we give quality in % but I want to compress the image according to kb and MB.

Comment: That is the way JPEG has been designed. If you want to get a certain file-size you can only do try-and-error because on JPEG the image content also has an effect to the gained file-size, so predictions are pretty complicated. BTW: You don't do it in "android studio". that is just the IDE (you could just use notepad instead), you do it in your app that is developed in Java.